# Properties of published nested components are not saved, events are not visible in object inspector

Tags: components, delphi-xe5

I created a component with following contents:

```
TEditLine = class(TCustomControl)
strict private
  FCaptionLabel: TLabel;
  FUnitLabel: TLabel;
  FEdit: TMyEdit;
end;
```

Then I started to propagate necessary properties of nested components by creating of corresponding getter/setter pairs.

Suddenly I thought, it may be easier to publish these nested components themselves as read-only properties so that when some new property or method gets introduced to one of these components, no changes in container component interface are required:

```
TEditLine = class(TCustomControl)
strict private
  FCaptionLabel: TLabel;
  FUnitLabel: TLabel;
  FEdit: TMyEdit;
published
  property CaptionLabel: TLabel read FCaptionLabel;
  property UnitLabel: TLabel read FUnitLabel;
  property Edit: TMyEdit read FEdit;
end;
```

When I put the component on a form, I see CaptionLabel, UnitLabel and Edit in Object Inspector, but that is all I can achieve.

- Properties of nested components are not saved to DFM.
- Their events are not visible in object inspector.

Is it generally a good idea to do so? How I solve the two issues listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TComponent`-based properties are treated as references to external components by default, unless you call [`SetSubComponent(True)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.SetSubComponent) on the objects that back them, eg:

```
TEditLine = class(TCustomControl)
strict private
  FCaptionLabel: TLabel;
  FUnitLabel: TLabel;
  FEdit: TMyEdit;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
published
  property CaptionLabel: TLabel read FCaptionLabel;
  property UnitLabel: TLabel read FUnitLabel;
  property Edit: TMyEdit read FEdit;
end;

... 

constructor TEditLine.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ...
  FCaptionLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FCaptionLabel.Parent := Self;
  FCaptionLabel.SetSubComponent(True); // <-- ADD THIS
  ...
  FUnitLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FUnitLabel.Parent := Self;
  FUnitLabel.SetSubComponent(True); // <-- ADD THIS
  ...
  FEdit := TMyEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.Parent := Self;
  FEdit.SetSubComponent(True); // <-- ADD THIS
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Wonderful! It works. Now I will look whether I could prevent some nested components' properties from appearing in DFM.

Comment: Look at [`UnlistPublishedProperty()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.UnlistPublishedProperty).  However, the better solution would be to simply derive your own classes from `TCustomLabel` and `TCustomEdit` and only promote the `protected` properties you want to `published` (you would likely need custom classes anyway just to use `UnlistPublishedProperty()` properly, so you don't remove properties from standard `TLabel`/`TEdit` components).

Comment: I would like to hide properties only when the custom edit is a part of `TEditLine`. If it appears on itself, all the properties should be available. The goal is not to maintain a separate class definition for the custom edit. If it comes to creation of a second class, I'd rather propagate necessary properties to `TEditLine` interface over getters and setters.

Comment: @Paul what you are asking for is not possible without delving into writing a custom design-time component/property editors. It would be simpler to create another base class, say `TCustomMyEdit`, that exposes only what `TEditLine` wants, and then use that class with `TEditLine`. Then derive `TMyEdit` from that base class to expose the rest of the properties as a standalone component.